# Rollup, TypeScript, Electron, React setup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, rollup

I'm trying to create a rollup setup for electron and react using typescript. That I get an Reference Error for `process` not being defined in /node_modules/react/index.js.

I created the following configuration files:

import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'

rollup-config.js:

```
export default [
   // electron
   {
      input: 'src/main.ts',
      output: [
         {
            file: 'build/main.js',
            format: 'cjs',
            sourcemap: true
         },
      ],
      plugins: [
         nodeResolve(),
         typescript({
            target: 'es5',
         }),
         commonjs({
            include: './node_modules/**',
         }),
         copy({
            targets: [
               { src: './src/index.html', dest: './build' }
            ]
         }),
      ]
   },
   // react
   {
      input: 'src/react/index.tsx',
      output: [
         {
            file: 'build/scripts.js',
            format: 'esm',
            sourcemap: true,
            globals: [
               'react',
            ],
         },
      ],
      plugins: [
         typescript({
            target: 'es5',
            module: 'ESNext',
         }),
         nodeResolve(),
         commonjs({
            include: './node_modules/**',
         }),
      ]
   }
]
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "lib": [
         "dom",
         "es2015",
         "es2016",
         "es2017"
      ],
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "importHelpers": true,
      "strict": true,
      "alwaysStrict": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "strictFunctionTypes": true,
      "strictBindCallApply": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "jsx": "react",
   },
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
   ]
}
```

I hope you can help me with this. I sadly can't figure out what the problem is.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled a little and got it working the way I want it to:

rollup.config.js

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript'
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'

export default [
   // electron
   {
      input: 'src/main.ts',
      output: [
         {
            file: 'build/main.js',
            format: 'cjs',
            sourcemap: true
         },
      ],
      plugins: [
         nodeResolve(),
         typescript(),
         commonjs({
            include: './node_modules/**',
         }),
         copy({
            targets: [
               { src: './src/index.html', dest: './build' }
            ]
         }),
      ]
   },
   // react
   {
      input: 'src/react/index.tsx',
      output: [
         {
            file: 'build/scripts.js',
            format: 'esm',
            sourcemap: true,
            globals: [
               'react',
            ],
         },
      ],
      plugins: [
         typescript({
            module: 'ESNext',
         }),
         commonjs({
            include: './node_modules/**',
         }),
         nodeResolve(),
         replace({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
         }),
      ]
   }
]
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "lib": [
         "dom",
         "es2015",
         "es2016",
         "es2017"
      ],
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "importHelpers": true,
      "strict": true,
      "alwaysStrict": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "strictFunctionTypes": true,
      "strictBindCallApply": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "jsx": "react",
   },
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
   ]
}
```